# Compile/Syntax Error: Run-time error 3075: Syntax error in query expression

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, runtime-error

I am using Access 2016 VBA. All code works fine, otherwise.

```
Public Function PopUp()

   Dim strSQL As String
   Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
   Dim db As DAO.Database

   strSQL = "SELECT PopUpReminders.*, PopUpReminders.ReminderCompletion, PopUpReminders.ReminderStartDate, PopUpReminders.Employee FROM PopUpReminders WHERE (((PopUpReminders.ReminderCompletion)=False) AND ((PopUpReminders.ReminderStartDate)<=Now() AND ((PopUpReminders.Employee)='" & Forms![Login]![txtUserName] & "'));"
   Set db = CurrentDb
   Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(strSQL)

   If rs.RecordCount = 0 Then
      'Do Nothing
   Else
      If rs.RecordCount > 0 Then
      Do
         DoCmd.OpenForm "SFPopUpReminder"
      Loop Until rs!ViewedRecord = True
      End If
   End If

   rs.Close
   Set rs = Nothing

End Function
```

The error that appears is (copied exactly)

> MS VB Run-time error 3075: Syntax error in query expression
>   '(((PopUpReminders.ReminderCompletion)=False) And
>   ((PopUpReminders.ReminderStartDate)<=Now() And ((PopUpReminders.Employee)='rerdeljac'));'.

Please note, "rerdeljac" is the logintext entered into the textbox on Forms![Login]![txtUserName] and which was matched to PopUpReminders.Employee; please note also that the error message does not include the remainder of the SQL code.

`(PopUpReminders.Employee)` is a field on a table filled only with text, and `Forms![Login]![txtUserName]` is a textbox on a form intended to be filled only with text characters.

The error occurs on the `Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(strSQL)` line.

Comment: Closing parenthesis missing?

Comment: Can't spot it directly, but suggest parenthesis counting. And I'm sure [little Bobby Tables](http://www.bobby-tables.com) would like to visit your login page.

Comment: PopUpReminders.* selects everything, you then go on to list fields/columns which will be renamed.

Comment: Clicking Debug and then compile allows the SQL query to pass without errors, I've checked the parentheses, they seem to work. Fionnuala, I'm honored you responded; I've read many of your posts and they are always informative. However, I'm unsure how a SELECT statement will rename my fields/columns? My goal with the SQL query is to use it to pull a specific set of records from the table in question, and then use those records to create a recordset. Does that help?

Comment: You flatter me! I am saying why are you selecting all columns and then selecting specific columns? The columns will be renamed to include the table name, so you will have, for example, both table1.field1 and field1.

Comment: BTW Debug is not much help with SQL, the usual way is to test in the query designer.

Comment: Isn't Now() VBA code rather than SQL? So your string should be `...PopUpReminders.ReminderStartDate)<=" & Now() & ...` rather than `PopUpReminders.ReminderStartDate)<=Now()`

Comment: Now() is still valid inside an MS Access SQL statement. Btw, if you were to use it textually, you also have to enclose it in `#`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your statement needs one more `)` right after `Now()` if I am counting right. Your SQL statement is overly complicated (probably because you copied it from a query you made using the GUI). This is sufficient:

```
"SELECT * FROM PopUpReminders WHERE ReminderCompletion=False AND ReminderStartDate<=Now() AND Employee='" & Forms![Login]![txtUserName] & "'"
```

This will fail if one of your users decides to type a `' (single quote)` in `txtUserName`. You should at least change it to `Replace(Forms![Login]![txtUserName],"'","''")`

Also `RecordCount` is not reliable. You should use `rs.EOF=False OR rs.BOF=False` to check if any records were returned and iterate through them with `rs.MoveFirst` and `rs.MoveNext`.

Comment: SunKnight, I love the simplicity of your code, and you are correct that I used the Create Query to create the SQL query, as my SQL is much worse than my VBA. When I tried your code, Access required parentheses, which I inserted. It then had a compile error on the comma immediately after [txtUserName], "expected )". Inserting the close parentheses prior to the comma gave the error: "Expected: end of statement" with the comma still highlighted; replacing the comma gave the same error with the "'" immediately following the close parentheses highlighted. Not sure how to fix.

Comment: um, side note since you brought it up, good point on the recordcount. thanks! (and thank goodness I've already written all that elsewhere so I can copy it!)

Comment: No parenthesis should be required, other than the ones in Now(). Something else is wrong. Try `MsgBox strSQL` to see what your query looks like.

Comment: Select all is generally deprecated, how about using an alias as well? say on the lines of `SELECT  p.ReminderCompletion, p.ReminderStartDate, p.Employee FROM PopUpReminders p
WHERE p.ReminderCompletion=False AND p.ReminderStartDate<=Now() AND p.Employee='username'` This works for me, of course you wil have to change username to the form reference.

Comment: That's unnecessary for a single table select. Specifying the table is only really needed for either clarity or if two tables linked together has a field with the same name (unless you know of another reason I don't?). Also based on the code he only really needs `ViewedRecord` in the `SELECT` so he could just use `SELECT ViewedRecord FROM PopUpReminders WHERE...` instead of the `*`.

Comment: Thinking of it, since he only iterates until `ViewedRecord=True` why not include that in the `WHERE` as well? Unless there is more VBA in the actual application that has been removed for clarity.

Comment: oboy, folks, you're losing me (& he is a she :D ). I don't know how to use `msgbox strSQL`; Fionnuala, I totally don't understand what you said about deprecation and alias; & putting ViewedRecord into the SQL query seems like it would defeat the purpose of the rest of the code, which is to cause the popup forms to open until the users click through each one.

Comment: Sorry for the he/she part! Anyway, add `msgbox strSQL` as a line of code right after `strSQL="SELECT...` That will create a popup with your actual SQL statement so you can see its final form. And honestly, I am having a hard time understanding the purpose of your code. If all you want to do is display `SFPopUpReminder` if there is a record with `ViewedRecord = True` which is what your current code seems to be trying to do, you are making things extremely more complicated for yourself than they need to be.

Comment: I think I may have found part of the problem. The field "Employee" in the table PopUpReminders is actually a combobox with a Row Source which is a Bound Column from another table, hence a query is being put inside another query. What do you think?

Comment: Then the actual field in question is probably numerical and not a text so you should remove the single quotes: `Employee='" & Forms![Login]![txtUserName] & "'"` to `Employee=" & Forms![Login]![txtUserName]`. Unless your form has a text box and not a similar combo box in which case you have to look up the EmployeeID (or similar field). You can do that either by linking the two tables or by using DLookup.

Comment: SunKnight0, it is much more complicated than you see here. Essentially, a manager can go to an entry subform on the manager's page, choose a user and start date, & write a message with subject which will appear on their initial login, i.e., "Call Customer X by 4pm". The pop-up will appear every time the user logs in until they mark it as completed. It is searchable by subject, date, user & trackable by managers on the manager's page & on a calendar.

Comment: Both tables and the form are text only. I thought about DLookup but couldn't figure out how to use it to create a recordset with which to achieve my goal. If you can show me how to do that, I'd be happy - and I'd have another tool for the toolkit! :)

Comment: That doesn't really change the current issue you are having, beyond the fact that your code as is would not work the way you think it would. I am short on time now, but if you provide you table structures for `PopUpReminders` and whatever table holds your list of employees, I can give you some better code sometime this week.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/n2eg7w82kkc0tpg/test.accdb?dl=0 is the location of the file. Feel free to peruse it, I'll leave it up until Monday morning. I've also left you a note inside it, SunKnight0. Thank you again for all your help, everyone!

Comment: Do you still need help or is the issue resolved? I see you fixed the error but does the code actually do what you want it to?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it was a combination of Fionnuala's removal of column names and SunKnight0's addition of the parentheses after the Now() that cured the issue. I can't put the answer to both, and SunKnight went way above and beyond so he gets the mark. Here is the corrected code, for those who might need it in the future:

```
strSQL = "SELECT PopUpReminders.* FROM PopUpReminders WHERE (((PopUpReminders.ReminderCompletion)=False) AND ((PopUpReminders.ReminderStartDate)<=Now()) AND ((PopUpReminders.Employee)='" & Forms![Login]![txtUserName] & "'));"
```